# Access downloaded files in a formula's test block

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm creating a Homebrew formula for a C library that includes its own test suite. As part of the `test` block for the formula, I'd like to run the tests that are included with the downloaded files. The tests run as a `make` target (`make test`). However, Homebrew `test` blocks run in their own temporary directory and the downloaded files are not in the path. That is, the following doesn't work because it can't find the files:

```
test do
  system "make", "test"
end
```

How can I access the location into which the files were originally downloaded and unpacked? I haven't been able to find any information about that in the docs. Or is there a better solution for Homebrew tests in this case?

Comment: I should be able to access the actual tarball with `self.cached_download`, but I have a feeling that the tarball is unpacked in the temp directory that the build happens in, which means I'd have to unpack it again in `test`. I guess that's not *so* bad, but it still kind of sucks.

Comment: Ugh, but if I do it that way, I'll need to parse all of the stuff written to STDOUT to see if any of the checks failed so that I can return a boolean. (Unless I'm entirely misunderstanding how the `test` block works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test do` block is meant to test if a formula has correctly been installed, not to run test suits. If the tests don’t take too long you can run them as part of the install:

```
def install
  # ...
  system "make", "test"
  # ...
end
```

To answer your question there’s no reliable way to get the original unpacked directory because it’s destroyed after install and the user may have deleted the cached tarball (with e.g. `brew cleanup`) so you’d have to re-download it.

A solution is to copy the necessary test files somewhere during the `install` step then use them directly or copy them in the current directory when testing, e.g.:

```
def install
  # ...
  libexec.install "tests"
end

test do
  cp_r (libexec/"tests"), "."
  cd "tests" do
    # I’m assuming the Makefile's paths can be given
    # as variables here.
    system "make", "test", "LIB=#{lib}", "INCLUDE=#{include}"
  end
end
```